# Issue with HTML / CSS floating towards right

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am trying to create a two column design with the second column having three sub columns.

```
            <div class="section group green">
                <div class="col span_1_of_4">
                    <div class="left">floatleft - </div>
                </div>  
                <div class="col span_3_of_4">
                    <div class="section group right">
                        <div class="col span_1_of_3 ">
                            To be placed on extreme left
                        </div>    
                        <div class="col span_1_of_3 ">
                            To be placed on center
                        </div>    
                        <div class="col span_1_of_3 ">
                           extreme right
                        </div>    
                    </div>    
                </div>  
            </div>
```

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/CBZZU/3/embedded/result/

Though the wrapper for second column (col span_3_of_4) has width more than 600px, every content is getting clumped towards the right. Even the sentences are getting into multiple lines irrespective of having enough size.

How can i avoid contents getting clumped to right?They should be placed in right side, but should occupy complete space instead of line breaking

Comment: You naming is confusing. you are wanting each of these in their respected sides? yet you give them all the left css class?

Comment: @DWolf : sorry for my mistake. I edited it and removed the wrong naming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this ? **http://jsfiddle.net/CBZZU/5/**

HTML :

```
<div class="section group green">
    <div class="col span_1_of_4 left">
        <div>floatleft - </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="col span_3_of_4 right">
        <div class="section group">
            <div class="col span_1_of_3 ">
                To be placed on extreme left
            </div>    
            <div class="col span_1_of_3 ">
                To be placed on center
            </div>    
            <div class="col span_1_of_3 ">
               extreme right
            </div>    
        </div>    
    </div>  
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.green {
    background:green;
}
.left {
    float:left;
    background:blue;
}
.right {
    width:100%:
    float:right;
    background:red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `div class="section group green"` gets shrinked because it's floated to right. Giving it `width: 100%` will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Add `width: 100%` to either `.group` or `.section`.